# When i reverse navigate the UITableViewController then app crashes why?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, crash, uitableview, tbxml

Actually My problem is....suppose i have an `UITableView` controller when i select a cell then it goes another controller which is also an `UITableView` controller.but when i return back from second controller to first `UITableView` controller then app crashes.Is there anyone who can answer my question??i am ready to send my code.if any one want to see the code then please tell me which portion i will give.

First Controller Contains

1. Three rows in one section and every rows is representing a value which is coming from a xml.as an example...
   --"TOTAL ORDER     (2)"....first cell
   --"PENDING ORDER   (3)"....second cell
   --"TODAYS ORDER    (4)"....Third cell
2. when i select any one cell then it goes to a new `UITableView` controller which shows the orders it may be "TOTAL ORDER","PENDING ORDER","TODAYS ORDER" from another xml link.

Now my problem is when i go to back to my first controller then after few seconds app crashes.i am not getting any problem..so please help me.

NOTE THAT: When app crashes then it does not give any crash report or any error in error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem it was because of i was calling uitableview row method while array is empty which is returning the number row in uitableview.

Answer (score 1):

Please use debugger to see on which point it crash.As I don't know the details of your Application...

you might wanna try....

[yourTableView reloadData];

best regards